# Cannot uninstall Avast Free Antivirus

Tags: windows, anti-virus, uninstall, avast

Why can't I uninstall Avast Free Antivirus? It always says "there is an error" that occurred and doesn't uninstall the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you exit the application first?

Try with [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

Comment: doesn't work, but I'll try disabling all the services of avast in safe mode. Ms config doesn't allow me to change the startup value of avast

Comment: Maybe you can change the startup state through Avast's options. Or use Autoruns http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: Better than Revo - http://geekuninstaller.com and has a portable and 64-bit support too.  Awesome stuff!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try [AppRemover](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/29/antivirus-software-uninstaller-appremover/):

> The portable software program that is compatible with Microsoft operating systems from Windows 2000 to the latest Windows 7 Beta (including 64-bit editions of XP and Vista) can be run right after download. It will scan the computer system for security software programs and display all that have been found in a list. It is possible to remove all or only selected ones from the system.

Answer (score 2):

In the past when I've had trouble uninstalling programs, sometimes the solution was to repair/reinstall them first.

Answer (score 1):

Avast has its own dedicated uninstall utility called **aswClear** for removing Avast software from your Windows PC computer.

Instructions For Avast removal using this utility can be found [here](http://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility).

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the problem you are facing is that there is an instance of Avast is running in background. So inorder to be able to remove the antivirus software please exit from it (just closing the window may not help).

If this dosen't work try using

[REVO UNINSTALLER](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) or [IOBIT UNINSTALLER](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)