# Unable to uninstall Avast and Avira

Tags: anti-virus, uninstall, avast, avira

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot uninstall Avast Free Antivirus](https://superuser.com/questions/119364/cannot-uninstall-avast-free-antivirus)

I have two antivirus programs installed (Avira and Avast), and it is really impacting performance. I tried uninstalling them using the *Add/Remove Programs* control panel applet, but I get an error massage.

I checked `Program Files` and some of the files seem to be missing (which may explain why they did not work correctly anyway).

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the name of the antivirus program? It sounds like it may be one of the **fake** av programs.

Comment: What antivirus software are you trying to remove? How are you trying to remove it? What is the error message it shows?

Comment: avira and avast
i try to remove it with normal way

Comment: Disable self defense. watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXiUpilme_4

Answer (score 4):

Why a program needs to be cleaned up after being uninstalled is a mystery, but some programs provide removal tools to clean up and properly uninstall them *after* they are "uninstalled".

Avira provides a [RegistryCleaner](http://www.avira.com/en/downloads#tools) which removes all of their registry keys. They used to also provide an "uninstall package", but that has since been removed, presumably because newer versions did not need it; so hopefully the RegistryCleaner will be sufficient.

Avast provides their own [Clear](http://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility) utility to clean up after themselves. (Avast also requests optional feedback as to the reason for uninstalling which you are free to provide.)

PCHell provides a [nice list](http://www.pchell.com/cgi-bin/perlfect/search/search.pl?p=1&lang=en&include=&exclude=&penalty=0&q=uninstall&mode=all) of antivirus uninstall/cleanup utilities.

Comment: Thanks for the tips..
i'll try this out as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

One way to properly uninstall programs that are missing chunks is to reinstall them so that files are replaced, and THEN uninstall it via Add/Remove.